# Indexing multi-dimensional array with tuple of indices from an indexing array - NumPy / Python

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have a 3-D numpy array `a` with dimensions `(6,m,n)`. I also have a 6-D boolean numpy array `b` with dimensions `(20,20,20,20,20,20)` that effectively works as a mask.

I would like to use the 6 values at each location `(m,n)` in the first array to retrieve the corresponding value in the second array. Effectively, I will compress the 3D int array into a 2D boolean array. I thought the solution would be using `np.where`, but I don't think it can deal with using values as indices.

The naive implementation for this will be something like:

```
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
         new_arr[i,j]=b[tuple(a[:,i,j])]
```

Is there any way to implement this without using a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Reshape `a` to `2D` keeping the first axis length as the same. Convert each thus 2D-flattened-block to a tuple and then index into `b`. This tuple-conversion leads to a packing of each elements along the first axis as an *indexer* to select an element each off `b`. Finally a reshaping is needed to get a `2D` output. Hence, the implementation would look something like this -

```
b[tuple(a.reshape(6,-1))].reshape(m,n)
```

Or, skip all that reshaping mess and simply do -

```
b[tuple(a)]
```

This does the same indexer creation and solves the problem.

**Approach #2**

Alternatively, we can also compute the flattened indices and then index into flattened `b` with those and extract relevant boolean values off it -

```
b.ravel()[np.ravel_multi_index(a,b.shape)]
```

Timings on a large dataset -

```
In [89]: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: m,n = 500,500
    ...: b = np.random.rand(20,20,20,20,20,20)>0.5
    ...: a = np.random.randint(0,20,(6,m,n))

In [90]: %timeit b[tuple(a)]
14.6 ms ± 184 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [91]: %timeit b.ravel()[np.ravel_multi_index(a,b.shape)]
7.35 ms ± 136 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Brilliant as usual

Comment: Thank you! Why does `tuple()` work on a 2-D array but not a 3-D array? I assumed it only worked for 1-D.

Comment: @rboz22 It does work on 3D array too as shown in the `b[tuple(a)]` method. After the tuple conversion, the packing is elementwise between those tuples to form an indexer and select one element each off `b`. This is also mentioned in the post.

Comment: Sorry, I posted the comment before the edit was made. For n-D arrays, along which dimension does `tuple()` convert values to indices? `tuple(a)` seems to yield very large values instead of `0<=i<20`.

Comment: @rboz22 `tuple(a)` would only collect elements off `a` into tuples. If elements in `a` are in 0<element_in_a<20, then `tuple(a)` would also be restricted to that 0-to-20 range.

Comment: Thank you. I realized I had a bug somewhere else.